# Proof that $F$ is continuous in fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, continuity

I am studying calculus and have arrived at the first FTC. In our book it states that:

let $f: [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous on the interval $[a,b]$ then we define the function
$F_f : [a,b]\to\mathbb{R} : x \mapsto F_f(x) := \int_a^x f(t)\,dt$

Then these properties hold:

- $F_f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$
- $F_f$ is differentiable on $]a,b[$
- $F_f$ is a primitive for $f$

The proof of the last two properties are quite understandable and also easy to find. However I am confused about the first property (supposedly the most straightforward one) where it states:

The continuity of $F_f$ follows immediately from the fact that for every $x,y \in [a,b]$ we have:

$|F_f(x) - F_f(y)| = \int_a^x f(t)\,dt - \int_a^y f(t)\,dt| = |\int_y^x f(t)\,dt| \leq \max_{x \in [a,b]} |f(x)|\cdot |x-y|$

Now here is what I am not sure of:

- Where it says $\max_{x \in [a,b]} |f(x)|$ are we talking about a different $x$ here? Like it could have been $\max_{t \in [a,b]} |f(t)|$, right?
- This statement seems true enough and understandable (assuming the above) however: how does continuity of $F_f$ follow from it?

Comment: The $\max_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|$ refers to the maximum value that $f$ attains on $[a,b]$ (which exists since $f$ is continuous and $[a,b]$ is a closed interval) - indeed using a different "dummy variable" such as $t$ would be less confusing there.

Comment: The given inequality actually implies that $F_f$ is Lipschitz continuous, which is a stronger condition than regular continuity. It would be a good exercise to look up this definition and show that it indeed implies continuity.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It would seem that this definition (from Wiki): In particular, a real-valued function f : R → R is called Lipschitz continuous if there exists a positive real constant K such that, for all real $x_1$ and $x_2$,

    $| f(x_1) − f(x_2) | \leq K | x_1 − x_2 |$ is trivially satisfied taking $| F_f(x) − F_f(y) | \leq K = \max_{x \in [a,b]} |f(x)| \cdot |x-y|$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Right.
- Call it $M$. That is, let $M=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}\bigl\lvert f(x)\bigr\rvert$. Then$$(\forall x,y\in[a,b]):\bigl\lvert F_f(x)-F_f(y)\bigr\rvert\leqslant M\lvert x-y\rvert.$$So, for any $\varepsilon>0$, if you take $\delta=\frac\varepsilon M$, then$$\lvert x-y\rvert<\delta=\frac\varepsilon M\implies\bigl\lvert F_f(x)-F_f(y)\bigr\rvert\leqslant M\lvert x-y\rvert<M\frac\varepsilon M=\varepsilon.$$

Comment: Thanks for a clear answer. I assume the m in the last part should be capital M. Also, we could use the extreme value theorem and then write $ \max |f(x)| $ instead of $\sup f(x)$ although for continuity of $F_f$ I don't think it matters.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo and I've edited my answer. Using $\sup$ instead of $\max$, we get a proof that holds for every Riemann-integrable functions, not just for the continuous ones.

Answer (score 1):

$F$ is continuous if

$\lim_\limits{x\to y} F(x) = F(y)$ for all $y$ in $[a,b]$

$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists \delta >0,\forall x,y \in [a,b]: |x-y|<\delta \implies |F(x) - F(y)|<\epsilon$

$F(x) - F(y) = \int_a^x f(x) \ dx - \int_a^y f(x) \ dx = \int_y^x f(x) \ dx$

$f(x)$ is bounded over the interval, and has a least upper bound.
Let $M$ be the least upper bound of $|f(x)|$

$M = \sup \{|f(x)|: x\in[x,y]\}$

$|\int_y^x f(x) \ dx| \le |x-y|M$

$\delta = \frac {\epsilon}{M}$

$F(x)$ is continuous.